# How to use one variable value into another variable in EJS, Node Express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
<% var percentage = (data.skills[i].rating / 10) * 100 %>
<div class="progress">
    <% var style = `style=width: percentage%` %>
    <div class="progress-bar color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="%= percentage %>"
                            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" <%= style %>>
         <span><%= percentage %>%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `<%-` for unescaped strings instead of `<%=` for style to work `<%- style %>`.

You forgot a `<` in front of `%=` here `aria-valuenow="%= percentage %>`

Also i'm not sure what you think this does `style=width: percentage%` since `percentage%` is just a string which will not be replaced by ejs engine.

So the correct code should look like bellow:

```
<% var percentage = (5 / 10) * 100 %>
<div class="progress">
    <% var style = `style="width: ${percentage}px"` %>
    <div class="progress-bar color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<%= percentage %>"
                            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" <%- style %>>
         <span><%= percentage %>%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can paste the code [in this playground](https://ionicabizau.github.io/ejs-playground/) to see what the output is.

Comment: such a small thing but it has huge implications , i can't believe i've missed the difference between = and - for the past 6 months ...